# Calculate the distance between a point and a line in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry

Im working on detecting a moving object when it makes an illegal move in the traffic(ex:getting out of the line). But because of the reversed coordinate system of Opencv it doesnt give me the right answer when i calculate it with the right formula. My line drawing functions:

```
cv2.line(firstFrame, (250, 0), (130, 480), (0,255,0), 1) # left line
cv2.line(firstFrame, (320, 0), (320, 480), (0,255,0), 1) # center line
cv2.line(firstFrame, (390, 0), (510, 480), (0,255,0), 1) # right line
```

And my line equations:

```
y +4x -1000 = 0 for the left line
y -4x +1560 = 0 for the right line
```

When my object moves towards left line, it starts to mess up the distance. when i see the calculated distance and my object's centroid coordinates, i found something strange:
[image]

There are distance(UZAKLIK) and coordinate(KONUM) values in the area between dotted lines. It says when my object was at (105,225), its distance to the line on the left was 1.212
So i drawed a circle in that coordinate and could see there is no way it can be near value 1. It should be at least 60 pixels. My distance calculator method for line on the left -where a and b are x,y values of the point- :

```py
def distanceFromLeft(a, b):
    nom = abs(a*1+b*4 -1000)
    denom = math.sqrt(17)
    return nom/denom
```

edit:thanks for all the answers. i figured out where is the problem : numerator part in my distance calculator is wrong. a and b should switch because a is the x value of the point and must be multiplied by coefficient of x in the line equation

Comment: -1000  is c of the right line, not of the left. And you should get your variable names right. Why is the point passed as a, b instead of x, y? Why is the numerator called x and the denominator y? It's really confusing to read the code.

Comment: @Thomas cv2 draws the left line for points : (250, 0), (130, 480) . when i put these values to line equation calculator it gives y+4x-1000=0 . sorry for the bad coding, i dont have much time left to deadline

Comment: coordinate systems. Y grows *down*. the left line has negative slope and positive y-intercept.

Comment: @Christoph thx for answer, what should i do to obtain right equations ? it made me feel so confused lol

Comment: Is it possible that you got your [equations from brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/)?

Comment: @Thomas no but this is the equation for calculating the distance which im using yes

Comment: Note that they have ax+by+c=0 while your lines have the formula ay+bx+c=0. So swap a and b. This gives 86.1 pixels, which looks ok

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [formula on brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/) I see that they say

> ax + by + c = 0

and you have

> (1)y + 4x - 1000 = 0

Note how x and y are in different positions. If you swap `a` and `b` in your formula, it returns 86.1 pixels, which is the correct value.

Maybe you want to make your solution a bit more object oriented:

```py
import math


class Line:
    def __init__(self, a_x, b_y, c):
        """
        Line in the form of ax+by+c=0
        :param c: offset at the y-axis
        """
        self.a = a_x
        self.b = b_y
        self.c = c

    def distance_to(self, x, y):
        nom = abs(self.a * x + self.b * y + self.c)
        denom = math.sqrt(self.a ** 2 + self.b ** 2)
        return nom / denom


left = Line(4, 1, -1000)
right = Line(-4, 1, 1560)
print(left.distance_to(105, 225))
print(right.distance_to(105, 225))
```

Comment: yes i noticed that a few minutes before u told me lol. thank you so much for your effort, i will try to be more attentive about my variables next time :)